# installing mavros on raspberry pi zero

Tags: rosdep, raspberrypi, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to install mavros on my raspberry pi zero
i follow the installation guide from mavros github

but when i running :

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y --os=debian:jessie
```

i got error :

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
>
> mavros: No definition of [sensor_msgs] for OS [debian]
>
> mavros_extras: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
>
> test_mavros: No definition of [control_toolbox] for OS [debian]
>
> mavros_msgs: No definition of [geometry_msgs] for OS [debian]

i'm using rasbian jessie with ros indigo

what can i do to resolve the issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259240/installing-mavros-on-raspberry-pi-zero/) by [fiersome](https://answers.ros.org/users/30022/fiersome/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-04-14**:
Please link to any instructions you are following.

**Comment by [fiersome](https://answers.ros.org/users/30022/fiersome/) on 2017-04-17**:
the instructions is from mavros installation guide in github :
https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/indigo-devel/mavros/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Binary builds of Indigo are not available on Debian Jessie. http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014

Debian Jessie builds are available for Kinetic by only on amd64 and armv8 which I believe does not overlap with the pi zero either. https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/tree/production/kinetic

So you'll likely need to build what you need from source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiersome](https://answers.ros.org/users/30022/fiersome/) on 2017-04-17**:
thanks, today i tried using kinetic to build mavros
using this :
https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md

but when i running :

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y
```

i got errors like in this picture :
[link of the picture](https://imgur.com/a/KPaqb)

**Comment by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) on 2017-06-21**:
As stated above, ROS doesn't have binary packages supporting the pi zero rn, so if you want to build mavros, you would have to build everything from source, http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source